# Container is not working after pulling nginx from docker hub

Tags: docker, nginx, ansible

I'm trying to pull `nginx` image from Docker Hub and run it locally with following `Ansible` storyboard.

```
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  vars:
    docker_info:
      registry: registry.hub.docker.com
      email: my@gmail.com
      username: myusername
      password: mypassword
  tasks:
    - name: log into docker hub registry
      docker_login:
        registry: "{{ docker_info.registry }}"
        email: "{{ docker_info.email }}"
        username: "{{ docker_info.username }}"
        password: "{{ docker_info.password }}"
    - name: Pull a container image
      docker_container:
        name: myngnix
        image: nginx
        pull: yes
        state: started
```

and Ansible output is as follow as showing it's working correctly:

```
PLAY [local] *********************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [log into docker hub registry] **********************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [Pull a container image] ****************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0
```

After that, I've browse `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:8080`, it was not working. But when I checked whether containers are running or not in console, it shows it's running.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
22f16edfd1e8        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        80/tcp              myngnix
```

Please let me know why it was not working. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not publishing the port `8080` on your host anywhere. Try this:

```
...
- name: Pull a container image
  docker_container:
    name: myngnix
    image: nginx
    pull: yes
    state: started
    published_ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Comment: ah, yes. I missed that. Thanks much.